# Python plotting: label without color code

Tags: python, matplotlib

In python using matplotlib, I used

`plt.hist(x,number, label = 'STH')`

```
plt.legend()
```

The problem is that the label is quite big and blocking some portion of the histogram plot.

Secondly, I do not want the color code to appear, i.e the text for the label has the default colour that variable 'x' has. I would only like the text to appear, without any colour.

So, how can I do that?

Comment: why the votedown? just say it here whatever improvement to the question u need..
And I searched in overflow. No such question is there. I don't think this question deserves a votedown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the legend look smaller so that it does not block your image, you can do

```
plt.legend(loc = 'best', prop={'size':11}) # 'best' automatically decides which is the best position for the legend
```

here you set the text size accordingly and also can change the position, in this case 'upper right'.

And for the colour not to appear in the label, you can use `plt.text(x position, y position, 'STH')`

Comment: Yes! this is a better answer than the first one. Actually, the absolutely correct one. Thank you! I just do not know why the votedown. How come you understood and whoever voted it down did not. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful to post an image of what you have. If all you want is to put the text 'STH' on the graph, then I would suggest using `plt.text` instead which will let you place the label wherever is best.

Comment: And I guess there is a limit of votes you have to reach before you are allowed to post a picture you want in your question..

Comment: I know. A picture makes things clear. But the question is clear enuf buddy. @Srivatsan understood it clearly. And gave the right answer. My hands are tied. So I cant post the picture.